# Plotly in R - Set trace names manually

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

Using `plot_ly` in R, I'm wanting to manually change the trace names from their values, to something different - anything at all -  (see commented out code), without having to add the `name` attribute in each `add_markers` and filter for each factor of `cyl` (in this reprex).

See code below:

```
library(plotly)
data(mtcars)


p <- plot_ly(
  data = mtcars,
  x = ~hp,
  y = ~drat,
  type = 'scatter',
  mode = 'markers',
  color = ~as.factor(cyl)
  # ,
  # name = list("4" = "4cyl",
  #             "6" = "6cyl",
  #             "8" = "8cyl")
)

p
```

I know it can be done with `ggplotly` by accessing `p$x$data[[trace_number]]$name` but obviously `plot_ly` charts don't have the same structure :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same with a native plotly chart by first running `plotly_build()` which

> creates the list object sent to plotly.js for rendering.

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
  data = mtcars,
  x = ~hp,
  y = ~drat,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  color = ~ as.factor(cyl)
)

pb <- plotly_build(p)

name <- list(
  "4" = "4cyl",
  "6" = "6cyl",
  "8" = "8cyl"
)

for (i in 1:3) {
  pb$x$data[[i]]$name <- name[[pb$x$data[[i]]$name]]
}

pb
```

[image]